# Enconding Problem from String to Bytes with double slash

Tags: python, byte, crc

I do not know how to solve this. For example if I give an argument to my code `\xFF\xFF\xFF\x0E\xFF\xFF`

when I do `value.encode()` it returns `\\xFF\\xFF\\xFF\\x0E\\xFF\\xFF` in `bytes` which is different from what I want.

**MY CODE:**

```
import crc8
import sys

value = sys.argv[1]
hash = crc8.crc8()

hash.update(value.encode())
print(hash.hexdigest())
```

**WHAT I NEED:**

```
import crc8
import sys


hash = crc8.crc8()

hash.update(b'\xFF\xFF\xFF\x0E\xFF\xFF')
print(hash.hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `value.encode()`, it is encoding a `str` to `bytes`. The string is literally made up of `\`, `x`, `F`, `F`, and so on. You've got to parse the `str` yourself.

If you don't care about validating the input (Read: you're writing a throw-away script that will only be executed by you), any of these hacks should do the job:

Remove all instances of `\x`, then use `binascii.unhexlify()`:

```py
import crc8
import sys
import binascii

value = binascii.unhexlify(sys.argv[1].replace(r"\x", ""))
hash = crc8.crc8()

hash.update(value)
print(hash.hexdigest())
```

Split the string at instances of `\x`, then call `int` with the 2nd argument (`base`) set to 16 on each of the `str` fragments, then package as `bytes`:

```py
import crc8
import sys

value = bytes(int(byte_str, 16) for byte_str in sys.argv[1].split(r"\x")[1:])
#value = bytes(map(lambda byte: int(byte, 16), sys.argv[1].split(r"\x")[1:]))
hash = crc8.crc8()

hash.update(value)
print(hash.hexdigest())
```

Or if you like living life on the edge, let Python do the parsing for you:

```py
import crc8
import sys

exec(f'value = b"{sys.argv[1]}"') # YOLO, FIDLAR!
hash = crc8.crc8()

hash.update(value)
print(hash.hexdigest())
```

If you're writing something that will be used in production, you really do need to carefully validate and parse your input.